# Leetcode: Why does my function say it's false on submission but true everywhere else?

Tags: javascript

Problem statement:

> Given two strings A and B of lowercase letters, return true if you can swap two letters in A so the result is equal to B, otherwise, return false. Swapping letters is defined as taking two indices i and j (0-indexed) such that i != j and swapping the characters at A[i] and A[j]. For example, swapping at indices 0 and 2 in `"abcd"` results in `"cbad"`.

So the submission says that it returned false but every other compiler says that it runs true, what's wrong? It's very difficult to get an answer on the leetcode forums so I've had to ask here instead:

```js
const characterMap = {};
let foundSwap = false;

var buddyStrings = function(A, B) {
    if(A.length !== B.length) return false;
    if(A === B) {
        let repeatMap = {};
        let foundDouble = false;
        [...A].forEach(char => {
            if(repeatMap[char] === undefined) {
                repeatMap[char] = 1;
            } else {
                repeatMap[char]++;
            }

            if(repeatMap[char] > 1) {
                foundDouble = true;
            }
        });
        
        return foundDouble;
    };
    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        // compare
        if(A[i] !== B[i]) {
            if(foundSwap) return false;
            if(characterMap[A[i]] === B[i]) foundSwap = true;
            characterMap[A[i]] = B[i];
        }
    }

    return true;
};

console.log(buddyStrings('de', 'ed'));
```

[image: What's wrong?]

Comment: How do you expect us to help? Where is your code? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Please post your code as _text_ in the question (paste it in, highlight it and click the `{}` button in the toolbar to format it).  Don't post your code as an image.

Comment: Also, what's leetcode?

Comment: @RocketHazmat It's a website for practicing programming.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here I'll edit the original comment to include the code. I'm not sure if the problem is in the code itself or just leetcode bugging out. Also leetcode is an online coding website where you answer interview questions.

Comment: @RocketHazmat is being sarcastic. He's been here for 11 years, he's seen hundreds of questions referencing leetcode.

Comment: It's not enough to just post the code. You also need to explain what it's supposed to do and what it's doing wrong.

Comment: @Barmar ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: Given two strings A and B of lowercase letters, return true if you can swap two letters in A so the result is equal to B, otherwise, return false.

Swapping letters is defined as taking two indices i and j (0-indexed) such that i != j and swapping the characters at A[i] and A[j]. For example, swapping at indices 0 and 2 in "abcd" results in "cbad".
What it's doing wrong is that in the testcases it says "outputted true" while in the submission it's outputting false.

Comment: Try calling `buddyStrings('de', 'ed')` twice in a row. The first time returns `true`, the second time returns `false`.

Comment: You need to declare `characterMap` and `foundSwap` locally to the function, not as global variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `characterMap` and `foundSwap` local variables. Otherwise, they hold on to the state from a previous call to the function, causing incorrect results if you call it twice.

In general, a "leet" coder should avoid using global variables unless really necessary.

```js
var buddyStrings = function(A, B) {
  const characterMap = {};
  let foundSwap = false;
  if (A.length !== B.length) return false;
  if (A === B) {
    let repeatMap = {};
    let foundDouble = false;
    [...A].forEach(char => {
      if (repeatMap[char] === undefined) {
        repeatMap[char] = 1;
      } else {
        repeatMap[char]++;
      }

      if (repeatMap[char] > 1) {
        foundDouble = true;
      }
    });

    return foundDouble;
  };
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    // compare
    if (A[i] !== B[i]) {
      if (foundSwap) return false;
      if (characterMap[A[i]] === B[i]) foundSwap = true;
      characterMap[A[i]] = B[i];
    }
  }

  return true;
};

console.log(buddyStrings('de', 'ed'));
console.log(buddyStrings('de', 'ed'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code stems from the fact that you are maintaining some state outside of the function between calls to the method. Calling the method twice with the same input gives a different answer. And thus when leetcode calls your method with different inputs it's getting a result that you are not expecting

```js
const characterMap = {};
let foundSwap = false;

var buddyStrings = function(A, B) {
    if(A.length !== B.length) return false;
    if(A === B) {
        let repeatMap = {};
        let foundDouble = false;
        [...A].forEach(char => {
            if(repeatMap[char] === undefined) {
                repeatMap[char] = 1;
            } else {
                repeatMap[char]++;
            }

            if(repeatMap[char] > 1) {
                foundDouble = true;
            }
        });
        
        return foundDouble;
    };
    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        // compare
        if(A[i] !== B[i]) {
            if(foundSwap) return false;
            if(characterMap[A[i]] === B[i]) foundSwap = true;
            characterMap[A[i]] = B[i];
        }
    }

    return true;
};

console.log(buddyStrings('de', 'ed'));
console.log(buddyStrings('de', 'ed'));
```

The solution here is to not have these as global variables:

```js
var buddyStrings = function(A, B) {
    const characterMap = {};
    let foundSwap = false;
    if(A.length !== B.length) return false;
    if(A === B) {
        let repeatMap = {};
        let foundDouble = false;
        [...A].forEach(char => {
            if(repeatMap[char] === undefined) {
                repeatMap[char] = 1;
            } else {
                repeatMap[char]++;
            }

            if(repeatMap[char] > 1) {
                foundDouble = true;
            }
        });
        
        return foundDouble;
    };
    for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        // compare
        if(A[i] !== B[i]) {
            if(foundSwap) return false;
            if(characterMap[A[i]] === B[i]) foundSwap = true;
            characterMap[A[i]] = B[i];
        }
    }

    return true;
};

console.log(buddyStrings('de', 'ed'));
console.log(buddyStrings('de', 'ed'));
```